# How to strech one RelativeLayout inside another?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got one RelativeLayout inside another one and I want the inside layout to have the same width as the outside.

What I have:

[image: one]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >    

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lady"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I need:

[image: two]

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner `RelativeLayout` width `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Margins

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >    

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

        android:layout_below="@+id/lady"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It makes my inner layout even smaller in width.

Comment: It turns out I have understood you correctly. Then just use margins.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is remove your `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` of your outer relative layout(**the padding was the gap from your first image**) and make your inner relative layout's width as `match_parent`

**example:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >    

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:layout_below="@+id/lady"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</RelativeLayout>
```